# Check if a given moment lies in same week than at least one datestring out of an array of datestrings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, backbone.js, momentjs

so in my backbone-app copyCLDRView I try to copy/paste weeks (and the underlying components/data). Or to be a little abstract, "copy one week and the models in the week into another week".

Now I generally want to implement a check if the target-week has at löeast one component on at least one day (targetweek from monday to sunday). To have a check if there are components in the targetweek, I have the following array of datestrings which contains all dates that have components:

```
        debug("[copyCLDRView::initialize] -> allDaysWithComponents: ", this.allDaysWithComponents);
```

which for example could contain the following values (Datestrings in format DDMMYYYY):

[copyCLDRView::initialize] -> allDaysWithComponents:  ["20042015", "21042015", "22042015", "23042015", "24042015", "27042015", "28042015", "29042015", "30042015", "01052015", "11052015", "12052015", "13052015", "14052015", "15052015", "18052015", "19052015", "20052015", "21052015", "22052015", "25052015", "26052015", "27052015", "28052015", "29052015", "01062015", "02062015", "03062015", "04062015", "05062015"]

Now I have to check if at least one of the logical dates in this array is in the same week than a given Moment.js-object (further called "moment"), which I managed to always be a monday.

```
paste: function (evt) {
        //this.selected is my momentobject, e.g. Mon May 18 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200
        if (this.selected && this.selected !== null) {
            //Here I need the check,
            //Pseudocode: if weekHasComponent(this.selected, alldaysWIthComponents) ...
            this.pasteData(this.selected, this.tmpStorage);
        }
    },
```

So in this example I chose the selected week to be the one starting with 18th of May 2015, now I want my check to return "true" when there is a component in at least one of the days of the week => looking above, it should return true if the array contains **at least one** of the following values: `18052015`, `19052015`, `20052015`, `21052015`, `22052015`

So I'm asking myself if moment.js could help me out with this comparison here, but I didn't find something yet and hope you could help.

Best regards,
Dominik

Comment: Use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: you can use moment to call week on it to check if two days are in the same week of the year, then compare year, something like . moment(date).week() === moment(date2).week() && moment(date).year() === moment(date2).year(). make sure you set correct local for the week so moment know it should start at Monday, default for US is Sunday.

Comment: @Nit Sorry, seems I'm not getting it, especially the built-in rangechecking. I just looked again into the docs :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create moment objects out of your various date strings, then compare them using `isSame` inside of a call to `Array.prototype.some` (or alternatively, you can use underscore.js or lodash)

```
var dates = ["20150101", "20150201"]
var testDate = moment("20150102", "YYYYMMDD")
dates.some(function(date){
  return moment(date, "YYYYMMDD").isSame(testDate,"week")
})
//Should return true for this first value of testDate

testDate = moment("20150115", "YYYYMMDD");
dates.some(function(date){
  return moment(date, "YYYYMMDD").isSame(testDate,"week")
})
//Should return false for this
```

Comment: oh, just forgot this question and figured it out myself some days ago. But thanks! :)